# How to make a multiline comment in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How do I comment a 'block' of code in Haskell? Example:

```
myReverse' :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse' [x] = [x]
myReverse' (x:xs) = myReverse xs ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
{-
myReverse' :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse' [x] = [x]
myReverse' (x:xs) = myReverse xs ++ [x]
-}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding a reference to the *Haskell report* where this is specified. To ensure that if later the specifications (slighlty) change, the answer is still valid.

Answer (score 8):

An important remark regarding this is that some *comment blocks* have a special meaning for Haskell compilers. These are wrapped in a block comment such that compilers that do not interpret this, will simply ignore these.

As the [Haskell wiki says on the `{-` and `-}` keywords](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7B-.2C_-.7D):

> Everything between `"{-"` **followed by a space** and `"-}"` is a block comment.

For example a compiler pragma is written between `{-# … #-}`. We can use this to enable extra features that are not standard Haskell:

> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
> ```

or we can use this to specify [rewrite rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) for a function if the parameters satisfy certain properties:

```
{-# RULES
  "map/map"    forall f g xs.  map f (map g xs) = map (f.g) xs
#-}
```

When we want to specify documentation for a module for example, we can make use of `{-| … |-}` to specify a [block for documentation](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/markup.html#idm140354810917952), for example:

> You can also use **Haskell's nested-comment style** for documentation
> annotations, which is sometimes more convenient when using multi-line
> comments:
>
> ```
> {-|
>   The 'square' function squares an integer.
>   It takes one argument, of type 'Int'.
> -}
> square :: Int -> Int
> square x = x * x
> ```

[*Liquid Haskell*](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/) makes use of `{-@ … @-}` to specify static properties that Liquid Haskell then will try to proof (or come up with a counter example):

> ```
> {-@ type Even = {v:Int | v mod 2 = 0} @-}
>
> {-@ zero'' :: Even @-}
> zero''     :: Int
> zero''     =  0
> ```

Such block comments can be meaningless if the compiler does not support pragma's, if you do not work with Haddock, or do not use Liquid Haskell, etc. But these comment blocks are thus often used to implement extra features that are not specified in the (official) Haskell documentation.